# Final Fantasy XV Comrades Standalone vs Season Pass

Tags: final-fantasy-15

As of December 13, 2018 Final Fantasy XV Multiplayer: Comrades is officially standalone from the first game as its own game. However, [on their website](https://finalfantasyxv.square-enix-games.com/en/comrades) they use the following wording to describe how this transition works and how new players can obtain the standalone multiplayer,

> FINAL FANTASY XV MULTIPLAYER: COMRADES is available to players who purchased FINAL FANTASY XV and the FINAL FANTASY XV Season Pass, FINAL FANTASY XV MULTIPLAYER: COMRADES or the previously-released FINAL FANTASY XV MULTIPLAYER EXPANSION: COMRADES (DLC version)

However, this wording is a bit unclear and doesn't clarify whether or not the multiplayer standalone is available to players who purchase the season pass after December 13, 2018. So my question is this:

**If I purchase the season pass for Final Fantasy XV after December 13, 2018, will I also be provided with the standalone Comrades multiplayer or will I have to purchase that separately?**